# Обработчик для определённого css-класса

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня по приложению разбросано множество форм с полями ввода денежных величин. Для удобства пользователя, который вставляет данные из разных внешних систем сделана замена запятой на точку, убираются пробелы - удобно, когда не надо вставлять то "1 111,11" то "1111.11".

И было это сделано в приложении на asp.net core с использованием идущего в комплекте jQuery.

Просто к нужным полям добавлялся специальный css-класс clean_money:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Vm.Amount"></label>
    <input asp-for="Vm.Amount" class="form-control clean_money" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Vm.Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

И глобально навешивался обработчик:

```
// fix money
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clean_money").keyup(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val === '')
            return;

        val = val.replace(' ', '');
        val = val.replace(',', '.');
        $(this).val(val);
    });
});
```

Теперь вот думаю, как лучше всего повторить подобную фичу в приложении на vue.js

Есть идеи, как сделать подобное красиво и просто? Хочется один раз объявить функцию чистки и минимальными средствами указывать, к каким полям применять её.

Comment: Обычно инпут - это отдельный компонент, который имеет определенный функционал и  настройки. Там все равно есть какой-то обработчик. По определенному флагу, он мог бы и удалять лишние пробелы. Но директива, это прикольный вариант. Так, что, думаю, дело вкуса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдет вариант с использованием [пользовательской директивы](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

```js
Vue.directive('clean-money', {
  inserted(el) {
    el.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      let val = el.value;
      if (val === '')
        return;
      el.value = val.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.');
    });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input v-clean-money class="form-control clean_money" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с использованием [примесей](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).
Указываем примеси в тех компонентах, где необходимо использовать метод.

```js
const cleanMoneyMixin = {
  methods: {
    cleanMoney(e) {
      const target = e.target;
      let val = target.value;
      if (val === '')
        return;
      target.value = val.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.');
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [cleanMoneyMixin]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control clean_money" @keyup="cleanMoney" />
  </div>
</div>
```

И наконец используем отдельный компонент, регистрируя его локально в родительском.

```js
const InputComponent = {

  template: '<input class="form-control clean_money" @keyup="cleanMoney" />',

  methods: {
    cleanMoney(e) {
      const target = e.target;
      let val = target.value;
      if (val === '')
        return;
      target.value = val.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.');
    }
  }
}


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'input-component': InputComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input-component/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не буду ставить пока галку - вдруг предложат ещё какие-то интересные альтернативные варианты - но с практической точки зрения это задачу решает и поэтому однозначно апвоут.

Comment: А как будут вести себя другие обработчики типа change, при работе такой директивы?

Comment: @Дмытрык не совсем понял к чему вы клоните. Если повесить обработчик события `change`, то его поведение вполне привычное.

Comment: Спасибо за идеи альтернативных вариантов. Из трёх вариантов мне первые два очень прям нравятся, вероятно остановлюсь на миксинах как более изученном приёме.